# Not required to import MapKit.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, mapkit, core-location

I'm making an app for my exam that uses the`MapKitView` and`CoreLocation` for getting different locations and adding pins to the map.

But I realized that I hadn't imported the `MapKit.framework` in the build settings, which I always was told to do. What I don't understand is that everything still works without it. I'm simply using "import MapKit" when I have to use it.

So my question is: Is it really necessary to import the framework in the build settings too? Some of the other students said that theirs dodn't work without it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enabled the "Maps" availability. Xcode automatically linked MapKit for you.

[image]

Comment: Oh okay, so when I write import MapKit it does that for me?

Comment: No, it does it when you turn on the switch on the picture above ;)